# Reading the file character by character in LibGDX(eclipse)?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, libgdx

I have a .txt file which contains  following text:

```
111000111001
x00000010001
111110000001
```

I want to put this content into string so I use this method.

```
public void read() {
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("map.txt");
        String text = file.readString();

        System.out.println(text.charAt(12));//Here is the problem,it's showing  empty character instead of x


    }
```

When I want to get the 12th element(x on 2nd line),it's impossible(I think there's a problem of passing to new line,but I don't know how to solve it).Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

There's something called **Carriage Return** that makes extra characters appear at the end of each line (3 extra characters to be precise) when reading from a text file so to avoid getting those in your way you can use:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");
```

And now when you try to print the 12th element you get the "x" you wanted

```
System.out.println(text.charAt(12)); // Prints x
```

Here's more info about the `replaceAll()` method: 
[Java Api: String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))